# convert an expression to a string representation?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Consider the following Haskell code:

```
module Expr where

    -- Variables are named by strings, assumed to be identifiers:

    type Variable = String

    -- Representation of expressions:

    data Expr = Const Integer
          | Var Variable
          | Plus Expr Expr
          | Minus Expr Expr
          | Mult Expr Expr
          deriving (Eq, Show)


    simplify :: Expr->Expr

    simplify (Mult (Const 0)(Var"x"))
     = Const 0 
    simplify (Mult (Var "x") (Const 0))
     = Const 0
    simplify (Plus (Const 0) (Var "x")) 
    = Var "x"
    simplify (Plus (Var "x") (Const 0))
     = Var "x" 
    simplify (Mult (Const 1) (Var"x")) 
    = Var "x"
    simplify (Mult(Var"x") (Const 1))
     = Var "x" 
    simplify (Minus (Var"x") (Const 0))
     = Var "x"
    simplify (Plus (Const x) (Const y)) 
    = Const (x + y)
    simplify (Minus (Const x) (Const y))
    = Const (x - y)
    simplify (Mult (Const x) (Const y))
     = Const (x * y)
    simplify x = x

    toString :: Expr->String
```

How can I convert an expression to a string representation?

e.g.

```
toString (Var "x") = "x"  
toString (Plus (Var "x") (Const 1)) = "x + 1"  
toString (Mult (Plus (Var "x") (Const 1)) (Var "y"))  
       = "(x + 1) * y"
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than call your function toString, it might be preferable to use the [Show type class](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/stdclasses.html).  Then your data type can be used anywhere that an instance of Show can be used.  Show is the standard Haskell way of converting "things" into strings.

```
instance Show Expr where
    show (Var "x") = "x"
    -- etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you almost have it.

Here's an example

```
toString (Plus e1 e2) = (toString e1) ++ " + " ++ (toString e2)
toString (Const i) = show i
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is everything you need to know for this: http://augustss.blogspot.com/2007/04/overloading-haskell-numbers-part-1.html